# Unexpected behavior when calling IDialogStack.Call

Tags: botframework

When I use the Call method, my dialog is indeed loaded however, from the emulator I first receive an empty message from the bot, only on my next message sent to the bot do I enter the dialog conversation.  Any ideas why this would be occurring?

```
context.Call<MyDialog>(new FormDialog<MyDialog>(new MyDialog()), Afterwards);
```

I'd like to go straight into my dialog conversation once I call `context.Call`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding the `PromptInStart` FormOption solved my problem, thanks.

```
context.Call<MyDialog>(new FormDialog<MyDialog>(new MyDialog(), options: FormOptions.PromptInStart), Afterwards);
```